# "git svn" Command not working for non standard svn repository

Tags: github, svn, git-bash, svn2git

I am trying to migrate an existing SVN repo to Github, I was successfull in migrating other svn repo to Github, but unable to do so with below. Below image shows the SVn url, and the repo.
[SVN Repo Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgSz3.png)

As per above image, DVAR-DA is trunk, and DVAR-DA-BRANCHES is branches. I am using below command, but all it deos is intialize a .git folder, and nothing else.

```
git svn clone http://vmdclsvnas501:18080/svn/rDVR --authors-file=authors.txt  --trunk=DVAR-DA --branches=DVAR-DA-BRANCHES --no-minimize-url
```

Can someone please help, what is the command, which can accept, DVAR-DA as trunk, DVAR-DA-BRANCHES as branches, with no tags, and it doesnt resolve the url to some other path either.

If it helps, my git config looks like below.

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = http://vmdclsvnas501:18080/svn/rDVR
    fetch = DVAR-DA:refs/remotes/origin/trunk
    branches = DVAR-DA-BRANCHES/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[svn]
    authorsfile = C:/Fazil/Svn2Git_DvarDa/authors.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

This may sound like a simple solution, but have you considered pulling down the repositories from SVN to disk, then using git to add the folders/code to GIT. That way you are not trying to combine/integrate source control management systems, just getting files from one system and then uploading them to another? It may be simpler and avoid a whole lot of (potentially unnecessary) complications.

The downside of this approach is that the version history of who did what will be lost. But if you are re-establishing a new code base, I would suggest that this might not be a critical factor going forward, the (new) changes in git will be logged against a user.

[Here is an article that may be of assistance.](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-and-Other-Systems-Migrating-to-Git)

Comment: The revision history is important for this migration, so i guess that wont be an option for me. But do you know of a way to do this.

Comment: Sorry I do not. But I would be interested in your solution when you get there.